# How to convert a json with a single value to a case class using play json

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have problems to find how to convert a json doc with a single value to a case class. Here is the json:

```
{
  "ax" : {
           "bx" : "value1",
           "by" : "value2
         }
}
```

Here are the case classes:

```
case class B(bx: String, by: String)
case class A(ax: B)
```

And here are the reads:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object Implicits {
     implicit val bReads: Reads[B] = (
        ( __ \ "bx" ).read[String] ~
        ( __ \ "by" ).read[String]
     ) ( B.apply _ )    

     implicit val aReads: Reads[A] = (
        ( __ \ "ax" ).read[B]
     ) ( A.apply _ )
}
```

The second implicit doesn't compile with the following error:

```
Error:(X, Y) overloaded method value read with alternatives:
(t: B)play.api.libs.json.Reads[B] <and>
(implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[B])play.api.libs.json.Reads[B]
cannot be applied to ((B, Option[String]) => A)
   ( __ \ "ax" ).read[B]
```

In order to make it work, I need to change the A class to have another value:

```
case class A(ax: B, temp: Option[String])
```

And the implicit read:

```
implicit val aReads: Reads[A] = (
   ( __ \ "ax" ).read[B] ~
   ( __ \ "temp" ).readNullable[String]
) ( A.apply _ )
```

How the reads can be done without having to add something that doesn't exists to the classes? Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: The `Reads` for `A` and `B` ought to go in their companion objects, and the implicits will be resolved correctly. Then, there is no need to import the implicits.. *unless* you need to switch them out for some reason. In which case, explicit calls would be more clear, anyway.

Comment: Thanks you. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Reads` instance for a single param case class is a bit awkward with Play JSON, but the following should work

```
 implicit val reads: Reads[A] =
    (JsPath \ "ax").read[B].map(A.apply)
```

Comment: what about the writes for a single value ?

Comment: can't overstate how helpful this is